# Why is it necessary to use "break" and "continue" statements in Java while loops?

Tags: java, while-loop, break, continue

When I create a Java while loop with an if/else statement inside (included below), why is it necessary to use the `break;`and `continue;` statements to continue the code?

I took notice that without the `break;` statement it only displays the `else` result infinitely.

For example, why does the code run straight from the `else` statement?

I know what break and continue do, I just need to better understand their usage.

```
public class TheClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x = 0;
        while (x <= 21){
            if(x < 21){
                System.out.println("You cannot drink because you are only " + x + " years old.");
                x++;
                continue;
            }else{
                System.out.println("You may drink because you are " + x + " years old.");
                break;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: In this context `continue` does nothing and can be removed. `break` is also not required it seems. EDIT: `break` is required because `x` will never be greater than 21.

Comment: if you what they are doing then why are you confused, please set a breakpoint and step through the code line by line to see why each statement is (or is not) important.

Comment: I didn't know breakpoints exist. These are actually quite helpful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is it Necessary To Use “break” and “continue” Statements In Java
>   While Loops?

It doesn't.
You need to use `break` and `continue` only if your statements are not enough to cover the logic that you want to apply.
It doesn't mean that it is necessarily bad but sometimes, it is overused and the code could be simpler without it.
Look at your code for example.

1)The `continue` is helpless.
After the `if` statement, the loop goes on. It is exactly what does `continue`.
It would make sense if you had some statements after the `else` statement and you would not execute but it is not the case.

2) The `break` could also be removed.
You break because the `while` condition doesn't take into consideration end of loop.
While `x < 21`, `x` is incremented but as `x` keeps this value after, so 
`while (x <= 21){` will always be true.

So you have to find a way to exit from the block `while` to avoid an infinite loop.
You do so a `break` in the `else`.

You can write the same logic without `break` if the `while` condition handles the exit condition.
You can do it by introducing a `boolean` variable that provides a natural way to exit the loop when the expected age is reached :

```
int x = 0;
boolean isAgeReached = false;

while (!isAgeReached) {
    if (x < 21) {
      System.out.println("You cannot drink because you are only " + x + " years old.");
      x++;

    } 
     else {
       System.out.println("You may drink because you are " + x + " years old.");
       isAgeReached = true;
    }
}
```

Or still simpler :

```
int x = 0;
while (x < 21) {
    System.out.println("You cannot drink because you are only " + x + " years old.");
    x++;
}

System.out.println("You may drink because you are " + x + " years old.");
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple: the else branch does not update `x`.

Therefore you are caught in and endless loop. The break breaks prevents that endless looping.

You start with `x` being 0. 0 is less than 21 - therefore your code to increase x is never taken. You probably want to change your condition to

```
if (x <= 21)
```

In general: you use continue/break in case were simple counting-to or while(some-condition) isn't sufficient. Meaning: these keywords are simply meant to give allow for jumping "out of loop execution". Either by immediately ending the loop (break); or by abort the *current* loop body and hoping to the next loop iteration (continue).

A good example for "break" is:

```
Value searchResult = null;
for (Value bar : items) {
  if (bar.equals(whatever)) {
    searchResult = bar;
    break;
  }
}
```

There is no need to compare other elements when you found a match - thus it is fine to break (when finding the *first* match is the goal).

Comment: In addition to what @GhostCat has said, `break` is also used to prevent any unnecessary continuation of the loop. In your loop, as soon as you get the result, use `break` to discontinue.

Comment: Armaiti, can you please provide me with an example of unnecessary continuation? It would be quite helpful, as I learn through example.

Comment: @duke7553 I updated my answer with an example for that.

Answer (score 0):

`int x = 0;`
This is fairly normal, nothing to see here.
`while (x <= 21) {`
Okay, so now we know that the entire time `x` is less than or equal to 21, the while loop will execute. This means that `x` will have take on a value of 22 for the loop to exit.

```

```
if(x < 21){
    System.out.println("You cannot drink because you are only " + x + " years old.");
    x++;
    continue;
}
```

```

Now, if and only if we're in the first 21 iterations of our while loop (i.e. `x < 21`), make a print statement and increment `x`. Here, `continue` doesn't actually do anything, and can be removed without any ill consequences. This is because the only other statement in this loop is an else loop, so it will not execute anyways. 
```

```
else { // If x >= 21
    System.out.println("You may drink because you are " + x + " years old.");
    break;
}
```

```
Now, if `x` is not less than 21, we'll make a print and exit the loop. The reason why this break is necessary is because x will be 21 when it first enters the loop. However, the conditional in the while loop allows `x=21` -- as a result, we have to manually break from the loop to exit.

This can simply be substituted with `x++;`, which I'd consider much better practice.